# SLDS - how to contain badges the same way pills can be contained?

Tags: lightning-design-system

I am trying to wrap slds-badge spans in a grid column so that when I have a long list of badges, they dont overflow outside of the container. Rather, they should wrap to a new line.

So far, I can see this behaviour with a slds-pill_container and a set of child slds-pill spans, but cannot constrain badges (which look much nicer) inside a grid column. They just spill over, rendering on a single horizontal axis.

Any suggestions on how to achieve a slds-grid, with a slds-col and then within that column get a long set of slds-badge elements to wrap to fit the current width would be most appreciated. I just cant get there!